Trouble deploying Milvus on my Google Cloud server and connect to it as a client
I am hosting a virtual machine on Google Cloud and run a Docker container to host Milvus server on that. I use VSCode's Remote Explorer. When I access to it as a client, it prints out errors like this:
[search] retry:19, cost: 3.00s, reason: <_InactiveRpcError: StatusCode. UNAVAILABLE, failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv6:%5B::1%5D:19530: Failed to connect to remote host: Connection refused>
The side effect was that I couldn't connect to the server anymore, including all services I deployed. It keeps connecting forever.
Image of my VS Code Terminal
I tried turn off and on the machine multiple times but the problem wasn't solved. I hope someone would help me to find the solution for my problem.

what's the detail command you used to run your milvus? And how did you write your client code for connection?
